# Avoid to print the if conditions in mvc3 helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I created a helper to build a list my problem it's that each time that if expression it's evaluate prints the value with true or false in my html. How can I avoid this behavior???

Here's my helper

```
@helper elementTipificacion(IEnumerable<prueba.Models.Tipificacion> datos){

foreach (var item in @datos)
{
    if (@item.Tipificacion1.Count > 0) <--- this the expression thay print's true or false
    {
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="tipificacion-@item.IdTipificacion">@item.Nombre</a>
            <ul>
                @elementTipificacion(@item.Tipificacion1)
                </ul>    
        </li>
    }
    else{
        <li>
            <a href="#" id="tipificacion-@item.IdTipificacion">@item.Nombre</a>
        </li>
    }

    @datos.ToList().Remove(@item);
}
}
```

And this the output

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have too many `@`. Use `@` only when you want to output a server side variable to the HTML. When you are inside a server side statement such as foreach, if, ... don't use @:

```
@helper elementTipificacion(IEnumerable<prueba.Models.Tipificacion> datos)
{
    foreach (var item in datos)
    {
        if (item.Tipificacion1.Count > 0)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="tipificacion-@item.IdTipificacion">
                    @item.Nombre
                </a>
                <ul>
                    @elementTipificacion(@item.Tipificacion1)
                </ul>    
            </li>
        }
        else
        {
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="tipificacion-@item.IdTipificacion">
                    @item.Nombre
                </a>
            </li>
        }

        datos.ToList().Remove(item); // <!-- not sure the usefulness of this line
        // The .ToList() extension method returns a new list everytime you call it
        // and you don't seem to be doing anything with the result of it, you don't even
        // assign it to a variable
    }
}
```